# Why I can' see my project? |Eevee render| Blender 2.93

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine

**Can anyone help me?**

Why when I use Eevee rendering, in render mode, the house looks so black and nothing is understood, and in Render Mode it looks the same as in Material Preview. I'm new to Blender and I don't understand why it looks so.

[image: |Eevee| Display in solid mode]

[image: |Eevee| Display in render preview]

Comment: hello, have you put some lights? Maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/cb8944bd37984ba8b546489d453af68e

Comment: I shared,and its not working with lights

Comment: it doesn't appear completely black here, but what happens if you move the light a bit?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: I hope someone will tell, it may be a problem of graphic card as I don't see the same thing as you

Comment: The light is just inside the corner of the building. Move it up on the Z axis and it's then fine in render preview.